# How to input a value sent from a barcode reader to a form's text field without opening the form?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, codeigniter-2

I have developed a very basic attendance taking system using barcode reader with PHP-MySQL. I have a form and there I have only one text input to receive value from barcode. After the form is submitted (my barcode reader automatically triggers submit) my script does some processing and then inserts values into my mysql database. This is working fine, but the problem is every time when someone gives attendance the operator needs to stop other works and open the form and keep it that way until the attendance giving is finished.

Now, is there any way by which I can create the the system like the operator doesn't have to open the form or pay any attention to it every time someone gives attendance? For your information I am running the application on local host.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but your barcode reader is connected to the computer and when it detects a bar code it simply simulates keyboard typing of that code right? as if you were manually typing the code yourself + adding the ENTER key to simulate a submit?

Comment: @Yaniro .. exactly... you got it right. :)

Comment: Ok, in that case let me venture yet another guess that you barcode reader is connected to your keyboard in parallel (or vice versa) in which case they are connected to the same PS2/USB socket in your computer.  If that is the case i think you have no other option but to have a dedicated computer for the barcode.  But, if you could conenct the barcode to another socket or another COM port you'll might be able to have both things (the secretary & the attendance app) on the same computer but you won't be able to do that with HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Yaniro for giving some thought about this topic. The barcode and the keyboard both are connected to the USB socket of the computer. And figuring out that I wouldn't be able to achieve the result using PHP or Javascript I have hired a programmer to do the task and he is doing it using C#.  thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope that I understood you right. Correct me if not.

When your barcode reader-software is able to do so, or if you can create a small program for the task:
The barcode reader software could run the default webbrowser with the forms url. Let the form url be `http://localhost/form.php` and use the GET method. So your software could send the data to the php script by querying `http://localhost/form.php?data=12345`.

Comment: Thank you Simon for your reply. I don't know how to do it, but still If I do what you suggested in your post, it will hamper the work of the operator. For example: say the operator is working in MS WOrd, but if suddenly Mozilla Firefox shows up (By your process, I guess it will) , it will surely hamper the work.  But  I wanted to have something that will do the task all silently. And just for your information My Baroode reader doesn't have any software; the automatic submit thing was set configuring the ROM. And if it is not possible with PHP, please let me know. :)

Comment: Hey did you notice- your name is Simon and my name is Srijon :)

Comment: PHP is a server-side scripting language. So you have to hand over the read code from your reader to the server. Therefor you will need client-side software. If you want it to run in the background, you will need to set up a service for the task on the client. But I guess, without any further knowledge of your system, no one can help you further.